# Yii CDbHttpSession - very strange stored data

Tags: php, session, yii, cdbhttpsession

I use `CDbHttpSession` for store user's sessions.

```
'session' => array(
    'class'=>'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
    'connectionID'=>'db',
    'autoCreateSessionTable' => false,
    'sessionTableName' => 'sessions'
),
```

Database has table `sessions`, where store sessions data. On my local server session data like this:

```
prfrp__id|s:1:"1";prfrp__name|s:17:"me@example.com";prfrpemail|s:17:"me@example.com";prfrpactivateStatus|s:1:"1";prfrp__states|a:2:{s:5:"email";b:1;s:14:"activateStatus";b:1;}
```

But on the application server session data string like this:

```
mOfOIHV7olQLvP3xR4Z-972ijv00x_qSTAgkCPiAuxKR0kCNrSID1RsmX5h3oCbjUi0HIfdVBxAH1gOTQc26ewexrEVCyh8jYlnP2vG1v_C_9hXLRKrASx8Cu_6cEsj9opCBNnqC0wkgFagKfT5t9-R-HcbnObL0b1CadQGJrCLxUvjQScyg6NZzEYXB32cndGHIGiIbEC5ugmISCia8Zfxze6Hba-OfmU9VQ_7lc2KvSUKbfXDH41cNltvGWlDmmKT3E6DXlnLIF9H3hFRt5g..
```

I use Yii 1.1.14.

Tell me please, where can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your application server, do you have Suhosin turned on? I've had issues with it causing issues with DB stored sessions in the past.

Comment: than you very much! I disabled suhosin, and all work ok.